# const err = new MongooseError(message);

Tags: mern

i was making an api but i got here an error

the error:

```
const err = new MongooseError(message);
```

full error:

```
MongooseError: Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\path%\path%\path%\path%\path\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:158:23)
```

Please help me i cant solve this error

Comment: C:\Users\Prakhar\Desktop\React js\Vedates\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:158
          const err = new MongooseError(message);
                      ^

MongooseError: Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Prakhar\Desktop\React js\Vedates\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:158:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7)

Comment: If you want to provide additional information, please [edit] your question.